# RegEx to split on commas, but excluding those within braces, brackets, and parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a comma-separated list, while omitting commas that fall within inner structures defined by braces, brackets, or parenthesis. For example, this string:

```
'text:firstName,css:{left:x,top:y},values:["a","b"],visible:(true,false),broken:["str", 1, {}, [],()]'
```

Should split as:

```
text:firstName
css:{left:x,top:y}
values:["a","b"]
visible:(true,false)
broken:["str", 1, {}, [],()]
```

So far, I've got the following... which is close but breaks on nested structures:

```
[^,\[\]{}]+(({|\[)[^\[\]{}]*(}|\]))?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you modify your data source to produce proper JSON? Then it's trivial...

Comment: For my scenario, it'll be more efficient to separate, bind, and cache the individual binding strings rather than doing them all as a group.

Comment: Then store them in a way that makes them easy to separate. For example, as a JSON array of strings (if you hate an array of objects).

Comment: Regular Expressions are used to represent elements in [Regular Grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) and a regular grammar cannot capture the arbitrary nesting of braces, so I don't think you can parse this directly with a single pass of a regular expression.  That is not to say that regular expression could not be part of a parsing solution, but it will be more complicated than `myRegex.exec(str)`.  Sorry.

Comment: Change the input format or you're going nowhere (you could crawl the string, counting parentheses, but that's hard).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are willing to change your data format, or you can find an easy way to turn it into proper JSON after receiving, your best bet is parsing manually.

The simplest matcher (assumes "nice" values):

```
On ([{   - increment parens
On )]}   - decrement parens or emit error if parens is zero
On ,     - emit and reset the buffer if parens is zero (finish a match)
If not , - push into the output buffer
```

This doesn't work with "ugly" strings (quoted parens, escaped quotes, escaped escapes...). This parser should parse all valid input correctly, while still being relatively simplistic:

```
On ([{ - increment parens if the state is "start". Push to buffer.
On )]} - decrement parens if the state is "start" and parens is positive.
         Emit an error if parens is zero. Push to buffer.
On ,   - emit and reset the buffer if parens is zero and the state is "start"
         (finish a match). Push to buffer.
On \   - Push to buffer, and push and read the next symbol as well.
On '   - If the state is "start", change the state to "squote", and vice versa.
         Push to buffer.
On "   - If the state is "start", change the state to "dquote", and vice versa.
         Push to buffer.
On EOF - Emit error if parens is not zero or the state is not "start".
```

Here's a sketch of the implementation in Javascript:

```
function splitLiteralBodyByCommas(input){
  var out = [];
  var iLen = input.length;
  var parens = 0;
  var state = "";
  var buffer = ""; //using string for simplicity, but an array might be faster

  for(var i=0; i<iLen; i++){
    if(input[i] == ',' && !parens && !state){
      out.push(buffer);
      buffer = ""; 
    }else{
      buffer += input[i];
    }
    switch(input[i]){
      case '(':
      case '[':
      case '{':
        if(!state) parens++;
        break;
      case ')':
      case ']':
      case '}':
        if(!state) if(!parens--)
          throw new SyntaxError("closing paren, but no opening");
        break;
      case '"':
        if(!state) state = '"';
        else if(state === '"') state = '';
        break;
      case "'":
        if(!state) state = "'";
        else if(state === "'") state = '';
        break;
      case '\\':
        buffer += input[++i];
        break;
    }//end of switch-input
  }//end of for-input
  if(state || parens)
    throw new SyntaxError("unfinished input");
  out.push(buffer);
  return out;
}
```

This parser still has its flaws:

It allows closing parens with braces et al. To solve this, make `parens` a stack of symbols; if the opening and closing symbol don't match, raise an exception.

It allows malformed unicode-escaped strings. `\utest` is accepted by the parser.

It allows a top-level comma to be escaped. This is probably not a fault: `\,,\,` is a valid string, containing two top-level escaped commas separated by an unescaped one.

A trailing backslash produces unexpected output. Again, this would be fixed by reading the data we're escaping. An easier fix is `buffer += input[++i] || ''` (append an empty string instead of `undefined`, but that allows invalid input.

It allows all sorts of other invalid input: `[""'']{'\\'}"a"` is just an example. A fix would need a better (more comlex) grammar, and accompanyingly more complex parser.

---

having said that, isn't it better to just use JSON for transmitting the data?

Option 1: a real object: `{"text":"firstName", "css":{`...
Option 2 (only if you *really* wish so): an array of strings: `["text:firstName, css:{`...

In both cases, `JSON.parse(input)` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursive matching:

```
(?>[^(){}[\], ]+:)?(?>(?>\([^()]*(?R)?[^()]*\))|(?>\[[^[\]]*(?R)?[^[\]]*\])|(?>{[^{}]*(?R)?[^{}]*})|(?>[^(){}[\], ]+))
```

The first part matches up to and including the colon:

```
(?>[^(){}[\], ]+:)?
```

The rest contains options for balanced `()`, `[]`, `{}`, and anything else except comma or space:

```
(?>(?>\([^()]*(?R)?[^()]*\))|
(?>\[[^[\]]*(?R)?[^[\]]*\])|
(?>{[^{}]*(?R)?[^{}]*})|
(?>[^(){}[\], ]+))
```